# ¿Cómo comprobar si el botón del ratón se suelta fuera del botón?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Estoy tratando de asignar algunos comportamientos a los botones, algunos ya los he logrado como:

1. **Cambiar el color del botón si el mouse está posicionado sobre él.**
2. **Restaurar el color del botón predeterminado.**
3. **Guardar el último botón pulsado en verde.**

Hoy me di cuenta de que cuando presiono un botón sin soltar el clic, y muevo el puntero del mouse fuera del botón y suelto el clic, se vuelve verde, pero sin haber ejecutado la función vinculada, me gustaría que el botón no cambiara de color. Estoy tratando de eliminar este comportamiento, pero no tengo ideas. El código es ejecutable, **funciona con python 3.7. Gracias**

```py
from tkinter import *

class TypeButton(Button):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs = {'font':('Calibri',9,'bold'), 'bg': '#11161d', 'fg':'white',
                  'width':10, 'bd':0, 'activebackground':'#bdfe04', **kwargs}
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)

class Example(Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.frame = Frame(self, bg='#11161d')
        self.frame .grid(padx=(10,10), pady=(6,6))
        self.container1 = None

        self.creator_buttons()
        #????????????????
        #self.bind_all("<B1-Motion>", self.callback)

    def creator_buttons(self):  

        mobiles = [['Persona1', 'Persona2', 'Persona3', 'Persona4', 'Persona5', 'Persona6', 'Persona7', 'Persona8', 'Persona9', 'Persona10', 'Persona11'],
                   ['Persona12', 'Persona13', 'Persona14', 'Persona15', 'Persona16', 'Persona17', 'Persona18', 'Persona19', 'Persona20', 'Persona21', 'Persona22']]                
        self.mobiles2 = ['Persona2','Persona9','Persona13','Persona21','Persona22'] 

        self.buttons22 = []
        for index1, mobil in enumerate(mobiles):
            for index2, texto in enumerate(mobil):
                number = 11 if index1 == 1 else 0

                btn = TypeButton (self.frame, text=texto, command= self.callback)            
                n1 = 5 if index2 == 0 else 0        
                n2 = 5 if index2 == 10 else 0
                btn .grid(column=index2 , row=index1 , pady=3, padx=(n1,n2))

                btn.bind("<Enter>", self.enter_mouse)
                btn.bind("<Leave>", self.leave_mouse)
                btn.bind("<Button-1>", self.clic_mouse)

                if texto in self.mobiles2: btn.config(fg='yellow')
                self.buttons22.append(btn)   

    def enter_mouse(self, event):
        widget1 = event.widget
        if not widget1 .cget('bg') == '#bdfe04': 
            widget1 .config(bg="#24364a")

    def leave_mouse(self, event):
        if not event.widget .cget('bg') == '#bdfe04':
            event.widget.config(bg='#11161d')                               

    def clic_mouse(self, event):
        widget1 = event.widget
        widget1.config(bg='#bdfe04', fg='black')
            
        if self.container1 is not None and self.container1 != widget1:
            if self.container1 .cget('text') in self.mobiles2:
                self.container1 .config (bg='#11161d', fg='yellow')
            else:
                self.container1 .config (bg='#11161d', fg='white')          
        self.container1 = widget1
    
    def callback(self):
        print('Closed')
 
root = Tk()
app = Example(root).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Quería intentar ayudarte, pero no puedo ejecutar tu código debido a una variable no definida. No te pido el código completo, pero podrías hacer que tu código se pueda ejecutar sin esos errores? es decir, que cuando ejecute tu código y haga lo de mantener el boton presionado, me pase lo mismo que a ti.

Comment: @DanteS lo siento al momento de publicar el código olvide que había cambiado algunos nombres de variables, pero ya lo puedes ejecutar sin problemas.

Comment: No hay problema c:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para que haya un color especifico cuando se presiona un boton no es necesario usar un bind, el widget Button ya ofrece dos opciones que hacen ese trabajo por ti. Y esas opciones funcionan bien incluso en el escenario que describes. Estoy hablando de activebackground y activeforeground.

Como dicen sus nombres, activebackground determina el color de fondo del boton cuando es presionado, y activeforeground hace eso mismo pero con el color del texto. Y lo mejor es que cuando el boton deja de ser presionado, los colores originales vuelven a aparecer!

Aquí te dejo el código del método `creator_buttons` con esa opción implementada:

```
def creator_buttons(self):  
    mobiles = [['Persona1', 'Persona2', 'Persona3', 'Persona4', 'Persona5', 'Persona6', 'Persona7', 'Persona8', 'Persona9', 'Persona10', 'Persona11'],
               ['Persona12', 'Persona13', 'Persona14', 'Persona15', 'Persona16', 'Persona17', 'Persona18', 'Persona19', 'Persona20', 'Persona21', 'Persona22']]                
    self.mobiles2 = ['Persona2','Persona9','Persona13','Persona21','Persona22'] 

    self.buttons22 = []
    for index1, mobil in enumerate(mobiles):
        for index2, texto in enumerate(mobil):
            number = 11 if index1 == 1 else 0

            btn = TypeButton (self.frame, text=texto, activebackground='#bdfe04', activeforeground='black', command= self.callback)            
            n1 = 5 if index2 == 0 else 0        
            n2 = 5 if index2 == 10 else 0
            btn .grid(column=index2 , row=index1 , pady=3, padx=(n1,n2))

            btn.bind("<Enter>", self.enter_mouse)
            btn.bind("<Leave>", self.leave_mouse)
            btn.bind("<Button-1>", self.clic_mouse)

            if texto in self.mobiles2: btn.config(fg='yellow')
            self.buttons22.append(btn)
```

Con esto podemos reducir el método clic_button a:

```
def clic_mouse(self, event):
    self.container1 = event.widget
```

Cuando planteaste tu problema, la primera pregunta que me hice fue "¿existe algo en tkinter que haga lo que el intenta?". Entonces busqué en [mi pagina favorita sobre tkinter](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/button.html) y me encontré que la respuesta era "sí".

Comment: Te olvidaste de un detalle, ```activebackground``` y ```activeforeground```. Estas opciones solo funcionan para algunos elementos y en algunas plataformas solo sera visible cuando se hace click sobre el widget. Pensando en este inconveniente y siguiendo una línea multiplataforma, es necesario usar ```bind```, claro que hay otras opciones pero ese ya es otro tema. La solución a esta pregunta esta en ```ButtonPress``` y ```ButtonRelease```. Gracias por la intención de ayudar.

Comment: De nada c: Podrías hacer una respuesta aclarando eso y con un código de ejemplo porfa? Vendría genial para aquellos que tengan tu mismo problema en un futuro.